# In a SharePoint Document library, how can you set the Details panel to be closed by default?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

We have an app with lots of links to content inside SharePoint folders. The pop-up window is kind of small. The Details panel always starts off open when you navigate to a folder, and it takes up half the window. Is there any way to set it so the Details panel starts off closed?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that we are using Document Sets. Once you navigate inside one of these document sets, the details pane automatically pops up.

Comment: Details Pane Is closed/hidden by default in SharePoint. I think it Is a  browser level or user level setting which opens the details pane if you have previously opens it for same/different folders and not closed.

Comment: It looks like its closed by default at the root, but we are using document sets. Once you navigate inside the document set, it auto pops up.

Comment: Yes, it opens up automatically for document sets - this is by default. I will have to check if there is any settings to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you click this (i) button? After clicking this button, the details panel will automatically open when we select the document. Clicking again will cancel this feature.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why my images won't display.It's the i button in the top right corner of the document library.